# android application link share using facebook request

Tags: android, facebook

Anyone know the way to share the android application market link using facebook by sent request to Facebook friends.

If any giant helpful me a lot.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add the parameter in the bundle while sharing the post.
Market URL is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<packagename>. If you are wondering how will you get the market link.

Comment: @Farooq Arshed 
In my code there is only few parameter 
1. to [to whom I need to send request (friend)]
2. message [What to show message into notification of request]
3. Data which is must be in string format

SO where I need to add link of play store with which key?, please specify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed page. In Publishing section click on Android SDK tab and you can see this snippet:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "This is a test message");
/* make the API call */
new Request(
    session,
    "/me/feed",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

I think you can use "link" field (with combination of name, caption, description or message).

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "Name of your app");
params.putString("message", "Your message");
params.putString("link", "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<your_package_name>");
```

And in addition you can link stories generated by your app with your app's Google Play listing. It's called "Deep Linking": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android

Comment: its done using same things before , any ways thanks this is the exact solution